# How to have an array batch in Apps Script insert a blank cell upon TypeError instead of stopping the data import?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have been working with a large-scale dataset of JSON links in Google Sheets that I'm looking to convert into data, and I have been having some success with this array batch code:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function dataImport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base JSON Import");
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base Data");
  var reqs = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [url]) => {
    if (url) {
      ar.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  //Storage of current data
  var bucket = [];
  var batchSize = 200;
  var batches = batchArray(reqs, batchSize);
  var startingBatch = scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber"));
  var processedBatches = scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"));

  console.log(`Total: ${reqs.length}.\n${batches.length} batches.`)

  if (processedBatches >= (batches.length - 1)) {
    console.log('All data has been processed already.');
  } else {
    //Start from the very last batch that stopped that needs to be processed.
    for (let i = startingBatch; i < batches.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Processing batch index #${parseInt(i)}`);
      try {
        var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(batches[i]);
        bucket.push(responses);
        //Remove previous batch index number
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("processedBatches");
        //Store latest sucessful batch index number
        scriptProperties.setProperty("processedBatches", parseInt(i));
      }
      //Catch the last batch index number where it stopped due to URL fetch exception
      catch (e) {
        //Remove the old batch number to be replaced with new batch number.
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("batchNumber");
        //Remember the last batch that encountered and error to be processed again in the next call.
        scriptProperties.setProperty("batchNumber", parseInt(i));
        console.log(`Batch index #${parseInt(i)} stopped`);
        break;
      }
    }

    const initialRes = [].concat.apply([], bucket);

    var temp = initialRes.reduce((ar, r) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position: { abbreviation }, dateOfBirth, hand: { displayValue }, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace: { city }, birthPlace: { state, country }, experience: { years }, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
        ar.push([id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, abbreviation, dateOfBirth, displayValue, jersey, debutYear, city, state, country, years, active]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    var res = [...temp];

    //Add table headers
    exportSheet.getLastRow() == 0 && exportSheet.appendRow(['IDs', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Display Name', 'Short Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Position', 'DOB', 'Hand', 'Jersey', 'Debut Year', 'City', 'State', 'Country', 'Years', 'Active']);

    //Add table data
    var result = () => {
      return temp.length != 0 && exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
    result() && console.log(`Processed: ${res.length}.`);
  }
}

//Function to chunk the request data based on batch sizes
function batchArray(arr, batchSize) {
  var batches = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
    batches.push(arr.slice(i, i + batchSize));
  }

  return batches;
}
```

I have been running into one issue, whenever the "abbreviation" variable cannot be found in one of the entries in the batch, it stops the whole code from working, and I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abbreviation')`. What I would like the code to do is if it finds one of those blank values, it just inserts a blank cell in its place and moves on (like it has been doing with other variables in this code on its own, such as the jersey and debutYear variables). Attached is a test sheet with a smaller sample size of data. The first batch should work just fine, then the next batch does not import, and the error message is seen.

I've tried reducing this code down to eliminate as many of the data pieces that I do not need that cause issues, tried changing which piece of the Position part of the JSON link it is pulling, and cross-referencing with a similar code of mine that has been working with no issues, all to no avail. I have also done numerous searches about this topic, but I have yet to find something that applies to the code I'm working with.

Edit: As suggested in the comments, I have made an attempt at doing a Try/Catch system to get the code to work; however, I think I did something wrong on that front as well, seeing as all this is doing is processing all the batches at once, then giving me the same error at the end of it. Here is the full code I unsuccessfully tried:

```
function getBaseJson() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base JSON Import");
  var countRow = 1;
  var page = 1;
  var url = "https://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/hockey/leagues/nhl/athletes?limit=1000&page=";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + page);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var result = JSON.parse(data);
  var { items, pageCount } = result;
  items = items.map(e => [e["$ref"]])
  var reqs = []
  for (var p = 2; p <= pageCount; p++) {
    reqs.push(url + p)
  }
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  var temp = responses.flatMap(r => r.getResponseCode() == 200 ? JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).items.map(e => [e["$ref"]]) : []);
  var res = [['JSONs'], ...items, ...temp];
  sheet.getRange(countRow, 1, res.length).setValues(res);
}

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function dataImport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base JSON Import");
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base Data");
  var reqs = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [url]) => {
    if (url) {
      ar.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  //Storage of current data
  var bucket = [];
  var batchSize = 200;
  var batches = batchArray(reqs, batchSize);
  var startingBatch = scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber"));
  var processedBatches = scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"));

  console.log(`Total: ${reqs.length}.\n${batches.length} batches.`)

  if (processedBatches >= (batches.length - 1)) {
    console.log('All data has been processed already.');
  } else {
    //Start from the very last batch that stopped that needs to be processed.
    for (let i = startingBatch; i < batches.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Processing batch index #${parseInt(i)}`);
      try {
        var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(batches[i]);
        bucket.push(responses);
        //Remove previous batch index number
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("processedBatches");
        //Store latest sucessful batch index number
        scriptProperties.setProperty("processedBatches", parseInt(i));
      }
      //Catch the last batch index number where it stopped due to URL fetch exception
      catch (e) {
        //Remove the old batch number to be replaced with new batch number.
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("batchNumber");
        //Remember the last batch that encountered and error to be processed again in the next call.
        scriptProperties.setProperty("batchNumber", parseInt(i));
        console.log(`Batch index #${parseInt(i)} stopped`);
        break;
      }
    }

    const initialRes = [].concat.apply([], bucket);

    var temp = initialRes.reduce((ar, r) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, dateOfBirth, hand: { displayValue }, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace: { city }, birthPlace: { state, country }, experience: { years }, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
        try {
          var { position: { abbreviation } } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
        }
        catch(err) {
          message.innerHTML = "Error: " + err + ".";
        }
        finally {
          var { position: { abbreviation } } = "None"
        }
        ar.push([id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, abbreviation, dateOfBirth, displayValue, jersey, debutYear, city, state, country, years, active]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    var res = [...temp];

    //Add table headers
    exportSheet.getLastRow() == 0 && exportSheet.appendRow(['IDs', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Display Name', 'Short Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Position', 'DOB', 'Hand', 'Jersey', 'Debut Year', 'City', 'State', 'Country', 'Years', 'Active']);

    //Add table data
    var result = () => {
      return temp.length != 0 && exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
    result() && console.log(`Processed: ${res.length}.`);
  }
}

//Function to chunk the request data based on batch sizes
function batchArray(arr, batchSize) {
  var batches = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
    batches.push(arr.slice(i, i + batchSize));
  }

  return batches;
}
```

Any help I can get to help fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Test Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eHjUYwApc4boUF8CSoWT56CIYfwWDKQZESfB8FUi0W8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you considered a try/catch? I use it in reading podcast documents for the same reason your suggesting.

Comment: I think Cooper's solution is spot on look at this [error handling article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: @Cooper, thank you for the suggestion. I have provided an edit in the original post to show what I tried using a try/catch. I think I did something wrong with it, but I'm not exactly sure how it is messing up in quite the way that it is.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, from your error message, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, from your error message of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abbreviation')`, how about the following modification?

In this modification, your showing 1st script is modified.

#### From:

```js
var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position: { abbreviation }, dateOfBirth, hand: { displayValue }, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace: { city }, birthPlace: { state, country }, experience: { years }, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
```

#### To:

```js
var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position, dateOfBirth, hand, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace, experience, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
var { abbreviation = null } = position || {};
var { displayValue = null } = hand || {};
var { city = null, state = null, country = null } = birthPlace || {};
var { years = null } = experience || {};
```

- By this modification, when a situation like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abbreviation')` occurs, an empty value is used.

Comment: That worked exactly like I was hoping it would, thank you! I think I was getting confused with how the JSON.parse was actually working, so that did exactly what I was hoping!

Comment: @DJ Luke Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.